# How can I display a user's username after successful php login?

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I cannot seem to get this to work following other peoples answers. So I have my files set up like this:

- Index
- Register
- Config
- Home
- Logout

*config.php*

```
<?php
// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$host = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
try { 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host}; dbname={$dbname}; charset=utf8",
                   $username, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
?>
```

And in my `home.php`, which is the page it will redirect you to after a successful login I want it to show the username, like, "Hello, {username}"... However I am having some trouble achieving this.

*home.php* were I want the username to show:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello, {USERNAME HERE!!}</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Where '{USERNAME HERE!!}' would be some php code that would allow the username to be shown there.

I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to show the username of the person who signed up.

Comment: If you're using sessions as I see from `session_start();` then you need to assign a session variable to it. `$_SESSION['username'] = "John";` then `echo $_SESSION['username'];` - `session_start();` is required to be inside all files using sessions.

Comment: So you are saying that i need to add `$_SESSION['username'] = "username';` to config.php and then use the `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` to the home.php?

Comment: Yes, but `home.php` should also have the `session-start();`. Else it will not work.

Comment: So where should i put the session_start(); on home.php? In the navbar or in the top php code?

Comment: Start a session at the top of every page you want to use the variables on. Basically you would get something like `session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['username']) echo 'hey ' . $_SESSION['username'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your config.php page:

```
    $_SESSION["username"] = "xxx";
```

on your home.php start a session as

```
       session_start();
```

and wherever you want to put the username:

```
     <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
```

in your case most probably will be :

```
    <li><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></a></li>
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that i'm a bit new to PHP. Not exactly sure what this means or where i would put the `<a href="home.php?variable=<?php $username?>">click</a>`

Comment: before I can answer that, how do you go from from config.php to home.php, button? link?

Comment: On register.php you click sign up and it sends the information through config.php and then it will redirect back to the index.php where you can login from there.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment on your post:
You want to start the session on the top of each page using `session_start()` at the top of each page.
If on another page you set the variable `$_SESSION['username']`, you can call that.

The following code will show a login form if the user is logged in, else it'll show other stuff:

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo '<li><a href="#">Hello,'. $_SESSION["username"] . '</a></li>';
  echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>';
} else {
//put login form or include here.
}
?>
</ul>
```

I also saw the suggestion of $_GET[x], but that isn't the best option. $_GET[x] is used to get variables from link (i.e. index.php?username=Foo), where $_GET['username'] gives Foo. This is useful if you want to sent some information from 1 page to another, but not great for usernames, as they are persistent across the session and the links can be edited.

Also I would like to say that my example isn't very great unless you unset the username when the user logs out. It's better to have a boolean logged_in or anything like it keep track of whether the user is logged in and then proceed to check if the session has a username.

Comment: How do I get it so it replaces {USERNAME HERE!!} with the actual username of the person?

Comment: For some odd reason it just says "Hello,username" like its pulling "username" directly from the config.php variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Brackets on the if statement? :D

Comment: I have made a test account on my site ( www.dotslashcoding.com ) with account details, username:test password:test. It updates after every change i make. You can test it out there if you would like.

Comment: It works for me when I use the code: `$_SESSION["username"] = 'Dave';` in my own environment now.
I see it showing up on your site as well. Now just replace Dave with the username of the user who logged in (on successful logon that can be either `$_POST['name']` or whatever you get from sql.

Comment: Hm. Okay maybe I should have explained better? I would like to pull the username from my SQL database and have it display the name directly from the database onto the navbar.

Comment: I think it's best to have it saved in the session when they are logged on. This saves needless database queries. Just get something like `$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['name']` when they submit a correct form and it'll be saved.
If the session is reset, they need to logon again.

If that isn't satisfactory, please take a look into http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Yes haha its been driving me absolutely crazy. But thank you so much for your time and help. I will experiment with what you have given me! Again, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving my own question with a very simple solution. I both love and hate when this happens...

All i did was this:

```
      <?php session_start(); ?>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
```

So all I really did was add:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```